# How and when martial art was originated, who originated it?

Tags: history, tai-chi

I have read of Bodhhidhharma's story, who taught Shaolin monks martial arts. I've read of Tai Chi to be the first martial art and root of all other. I've also read of Okinawa island where Japanese martial arts started. I understand Tai Chi and root of martial art is Yoga. What are the facts about history?

Comment: As interesting as the question is, it is too broad to be answered in its current form. I don't think you can have a really comprehensive answer here since a proper answer would be something entire books are written for. See the [faq#dontask] for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for the origin of Tai Chi? Or of the many different styles of martial arts? Or of martial arts in general?

Martial arts have existed as long as people have been fighting. And as often as people have been fighting, people have been figuring out better and more efficient ways of fighting, and teaching these methods to others. There is no one origin of martial arts. Every society that ever existed have developed their own. They all will have some similarities because there are only so many ways to throw a punch, swing a stick, etc. This similarity does not indicate that they all derived from one style, but that we all have the same anatomy.